# Moving Sprits location with location issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When i move my layer that's contain all sprits by scrolling, sprits location does't change.i want's to change my sprits location with scrolling. please give me some solution for this.

Thanks in Advance......

Comment: do you mean that the sprites are not moving on screen with the layer, or that `sprite.location` is returning the same value? how are you moving the layer?... can you provide the code

Answer (score 0):

```
// simple position update
CGPoint a = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch previousLocationInView:touch.view]];
CGPoint b = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:touch.view]];
CGPoint nowPosition = scrollLayer.position;
nowPosition.y += ( b.y - a.y );
nowPosition.y = MAX( 0, nowPosition.y );
nowPosition.y = MIN(20, nowPosition.y);
scrollLayer.position = nowPosition;
```

My scrollLayer contain all the sprits. This is the code by which my layer moves to a new location. All sprits also move with the layer but their position does not change with respect to the layer moving. When i touch on that possition the sprits move. But I want to touch on sprits for moving them.

Comment: Consider editing your question with this information instead of adding it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

if you move a layer without moving its child sprites, the `sprite.position` will return the same value even after moving the layer because its returning it relative to node space (layer). To get the position of the sprite according to the world or your scene you need to convert it to world space:

```
CGPoint worldPosition  = [self convertToWorldSpace:sprite.position];
```

i hope this answers your question because it wasnt very clear.